# Converting Data for Timeseries analysis using ets()

Tags: r, time-series

I have a csv file with the following data:

```
Year    1000 Barrels/Day
1/15/2000   239
2/15/2000   267
3/15/2000   162
4/15/2000   264
5/15/2000   170
6/15/2000   210
7/15/2000   264
8/15/2000   405
9/15/2000   352
10/15/2000  337
```

I ran the following code for it's conversion to timeseries format for processing.

```
library(xts)
library(forecast)
df<- read.csv("US-OIL.csv")
stocks <- xts(df[,-1], order.by=as.Date(df[,1], "%m/%d/%Y"))
ets(stocks)
```

But when I run the last line, I get the output with an **ETS(A,N,N)** model.
I am not sure why this is happening because, when I run `ets()` with a preloaded dataset `elecequip` in `library(fpp)` I get an output with `ETS(M,Ad,M)`
Not sure why this discrepancy. Please provide your comments in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are letting ets automatically choose a model based on AIC, AICcm or BIC. The data is different for the elecquip dataset, so the model is also different.

See slide 24:

http://robjhyndman.com/talks/RevolutionR/6-ETS.pdf

Comment: So does that mean my dataset doesn't have any seasonal trend?? Can you recommend an alternative of `ets()` that can be used for forecasting next 5 periods based on this data.??? Thanks

Comment: My recommendation is that you read this awesome book by the author of the forecast package: https://www.otexts.org/fpp. I think you need more data to make a forecast as you don't even have a full year I don't know how you can expect to estimate the seasonality (http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/short-time-series/). I would predict the average (267) for the next 5 periods.

Comment: The above is the sample of data that I have attached. The actual data consists of 172 rows(from year 2000 to 2014). Also when I try running the `HoltWinters(stocks)` I get the following error `Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods`. Any comments??

Comment: provide a reproducible example. Also accept this answer as correct and open a new question.

Comment: But this is no solution?? I'll open a new question for the other part. But you speculated that I don't have data over an year and I do. So the question still remains is why the model simple?? Do you want me to provide the data dump